# Prevent creating compressed file if compression breaks

Tags: c#

I am using this code to compress files:

```cs
public class GzipCompressor : ICompressor
{
    public void Compress(string input, string output)
    {
        using (FileStream originalFileStream = File.OpenRead(input))
        using (FileStream compressedFileStream = File.OpenWrite(output))
        using (GZipStream compressor = new GZipStream(compressedFileStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
            originalFileStream.CopyTo(compressor);
    }
}
```

The problem is that if someone closes the application while the file is compressing, the file will be saved to the destination path, but it will be invalid (it will not even be able to open it). Is there a way to avoid this? I would prefer such a file not to be created at all in such a situation.

Comment: Write to a file that the consuming app doesn't recognize, could be as simple as appending ".tmp" to the filename, rename afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [`Application.ApplicationExit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.applicationexit) to perform logic when the application is attempting to close down. Keep in mind that there's still a chance something catastrophic is occurring and you wont be able to clean everything up (if the computer is forcibly shut down, there's not much you can do). The documentation also mentions the following got'cha:

> Because this is a static event, you must detach any event handlers attached to this event in the `ApplicationExit` event handler itself. If you do not detach these handlers, they will remain attached to the event and continue to consume memory.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by using `GetTempFileName`. I will provide an example based on your example.

```
private FileInfo? _tmpFileInfo;

public void Compress(string input, string output)
{
    _tmpFileInfo = CreateTempFile();

    using (FileStream originalFileStream = File.OpenRead(input))
    using (FileStream compressedFileStream = File.OpenWrite(_tmpFileInfo!.FullName))
    using (GZipStream compressor = new GZipStream(compressedFileStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        originalFileStream.CopyTo(compressor);
    }

    File.Copy(_tmpFileInfo.FullName, output);
    File.Delete(_tmpFileInfo.FullName);
}
```

So basically what we do, is we create a temporary file and zip it to it, when it is done successfully, we copy it back to the output location. Here is `CreateTempFile` method:

```
public FileInfo? CreateTempFile()
{
    var fileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
    FileInfo? fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName)
    {
        Attributes = FileAttributes.Temporary
    };

    return fileInfo;
}
```

That is it.

If you need to delete the temp file while the application makes an unhandled exception or process exists or other events, you can create an event like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(GzipCompressor.ActionOnExit);
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(GzipCompressor.ActionOnExit);

    var zip = new GzipCompressor();

    zip.Compress(@"C:\temp\in\file1.txt", @"C:\temp\out\file1.txt.gz");
}
```

Then in your GzipCompressor class make FileInfo static.

```
private static FileInfo? _tmpFileInfo;
```

and create a static method to delete the temp file:

```
public static void ActionOnExit(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    File.Delete(_tmpFileInfo.FullName);
}
```

There is, of course, no 100% guarantee that the temp file is deleted, let's say if you turn the computer forcibly by powering it off. The same scenario is valid while it is copying the file.

> note: what regards the event in my answer, I tried it with a console app in dot net 6, but this should be cross-compatible with a dot net core, dot net framework, etc. read more about the [AppDomian](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain?view=net-6.0) events.

I left the full answer on github: https://github.com/maythamfahmi/BlogExamples/tree/main/Stackoverflow/TempFiles